# Slow connection from on-permise to Azure

Tags: azure, bandwidth, azure-virtual-network

We plan to migrate from on-premise to Azure. After deployment of a test virtual machine in Azure tenant we reported a slow connection (download and upload speed) mesured by using iperf: 16.5 Mbits/sec sender and 16.4 Mbits/sec receiver. And Via VPN tunnel: 15.6 Mbits/sec sender and 15.5 Mbits/sec receiver

The test virtual machine is not under heavy load, no applications are installed. No other vms are deployed in the virtual network. Someone knows what is causing this issue? We would be very grateful for any tips.

```
VM Size: Standard D2s_v4 (2 vcpus, 8 GiB memory)
Sorage type: Standard HDD LRS
Storage Size: 127GB
Storage Max IOPS: 500
Storage Max throughput (MBps): 60
Storage Encryption: SSE with PMK
```

We tested network performance also by using other Azure tenants with different virtual network topology, different vms size and operating systems, etc in all cases we got about 20Mb / 20Mb (download/upload).

Comment: Please provide more details on how you are connecting on-prem to Azure--S2S VPN, ExpressRoute, gateways, SKUs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Probably this issues results from bad interpretation of bandwidth measurement. I was conducting bandwidth tests using iperf. Then I used AzureCT - the Azure Connectivity Toolkit. In general, AzureCT is based on iperf, but it performs more complex tests. In the first case (iperf) I got the result for one tcp session (16 Mbit/sec), in the second case (AzureCT) for 32 simultaneous tcp sessions (489 Mbits/sec), as shown below:

```
1 Session                   16.0 Mbits/sec  0% loss         31.185ms
32 Sessions                 489 Mbits/sec   0% loss         31.225ms
```

Comment: are you test results based on the public ip? or the S2S?